# GRUB bootloader is bricked, cannot install any operating system

Tags: linux, grub

I accidentally installed debian on the wrong partition and now my GRUB bootloader is bricked. 
I tried installing other operating systems but I get the same error at the end: cannot install grub (whether grub 2 or LILO) 
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I think this should be over on serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: I fixed the problem by installing Windows. Windows fixed the whole issue by itself. Then I had to remove windows and install Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from a Live CD (you can do this from the Ubuntu install CD, among others) and re-configure grub via the command line.  You'll probably have a difficult time restoring your previous Grub, but you should at least be able to get your system back in a usable state.

For a more detailed answer, ask on superuser.com.  The folks over there are more experienced in this sort of thing.